# DataTables page 2 of pagination not calling Magnific Popup

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

So I have this DataTable with pagination enabled which I coded a way so the user can edit lines of a table, when the user calls the edit page it opens in a Magnific Popup, it all works well on page 1, from page 2 of the DataTable and ahead it stops calling the Magnific Popup and I just can't find out why...

The edit.php with the form which opens inside the Magnific Popup has this div:

```
<div id="ajax-content" class="example-popup">
```

And the following css:

```
position: relative;
background: #FFF;
padding: 10px;
width: auto;
max-width: 750px;
margin: 20px auto;
color: #999;
font-weight: bold;
```

At my index I have this function:

```
$('.popup-ajax').magnificPopup({
   type: 'ajax',
   showCloseBtn: 'true',
   modal: 'true',
});
```

And this link to call the function:

```
echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/teste/include/edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="popup-ajax">Editar</a></td>';
```

The process is Link which class calls the function and then opens the edit page inside the Magnific Popup.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Only first page elements are available in DOM, that is why your jQuery selector `$('.popup-ajax')` doesn't select elements from pages other than first.

#### SOLUTION

You need to initialize Magnific Popup inside callback defined by [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option. This function will be called every time the table has been redrawn.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   drawCallback: function(){
      $('.popup-ajax').magnificPopup({
         type: 'ajax',
         showCloseBtn: 'true',
         modal: 'true'
      });
   }
});
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Custom control does not work on second page and after](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-custom-control-does-not-work-on-second-page/) for more examples and details.

Comment: DANG! It works, well, kinda, it messed up with my DataTables initialization, it's not sorting it out properly, look at my two initializations:
https://pastebin.com/E8vZUM9w

Comment: @FernandoGross, you're initializing your table twice. Initialize your table once when DOM becomes ready.

Comment: You're a god, thank you! Here's the code for the correct initialization: https://pastebin.com/MynVdXKv